# Fetch distinct receivers from message model while preserving order

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a messaging app. Here's my model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    msg_content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is what I tried in the view:

```
data = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)).order_by('-created_at')
```

In the template:

```
{% for abc in data %}
    {{ abc.receiver }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Here I want to filter the distinct receivers and re-order them based upon the fact that to whom `request.user` sent new message recently (as we see on social media platforms).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Filter messages sent by *request.user*, order by `receiver_id` and  `-created_at` then use distinct on `receiver_id`

```
Message.objects.filter(sender=request.user).order_by('receiver_id','-created_at').distinct('receiver_id')
```

Comment: Sir, distinct is not working. It's still showing Receivers in equal number as Messages

Comment: i have updated my answer, hope this will help

Comment: previous answer was messy, i found a lot cleaner approach to do it. try this and let me know is this worked?